# search products in multicompany mode Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Impacted versions:
Odoo 10 CE with multi company

Description :
I'm trying to add random alphanumeric value to default_code of products 
it works fine in a single company Odoo but not in a multi-company instance

here's my functions that i'm calling in a cron who run every night

```
@api.multi
def affect_sku(self):
    _logger.info("running affect_sku")
    Product = self.env['product.product']
    _logger.info("Model ::: %s" % Product)
    product_ids = Product.search([('active', '=', True), ('default_code', '=', '')])
    _logger.info("Les Produits ::: %s " % product_ids)
    if product_ids:
        for product_id in product_ids:
            _logger.info("Product id : %s" % product_id)
            product = Product.browse(product_id.id)
            _logger.info("Old Product default code : %s" % product.default_code)
            x = self.randomStringDigits(13)
            y = self.env['product.product'].search([('active', '=', True), ('default_code', '=', x)])
            _logger.info("y = %s" % y)
            while y :
                x = self.randomStringDigits(13)
                y = self.env['product.product'].search([('active', '=', True), ('default_code', '=', x)])
            product.default_code = x
            _logger.info("SKU de %s : %s" % (product.id, product.default_code))
```

Comment: Can you please describe the exact problem you're having? Do you get any error messages? Or does your code stop somewhere?

Comment: the Product.seach() return an empty result  when i use the cron on multicompany

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SUPER USER` because he have the privilege to see all product, and you can enhance your code a little bit:

```py
# and use model for crons
@api.model
def affect_sku(self):
    _logger.info("running affect_sku")
    Product = self.env['product.product'].sudo() # use SUPER USER Jus to skip any access rights
    _logger.info("Model ::: %s" % Product)
    # no need to pass active it's passed by default
    product_ids = Product.search(['|', ('default_code', '=', ''), ('default_code', '=', False)])
    _logger.info("Les Produits ::: %s " % product_ids)
    # no need to check just loop directly
    for product in product_ids:
            _logger.info("Product id : %s" % product)
            # no need to browse it's all ready a record set
            _logger.info("Old Product default code : %s" % product.default_code)
            while True :
                random_code = self.randomStringDigits(13)
                # no need to pass active and use search_count
                if not self.env['product.product'].search_count([('default_code', '=', random_code )]):
                    break
            product.default_code = random_code
            _logger.info("SKU de %s : %s" % (product.id, product.default_code))
```

Comment: i tried as you told me and result still gets empty odoo.addons.custom_products.models.models: running affect_sku
odoo.addons.custom_products.models.models: Model ::: product.product()
odoo.addons.custom_products.models.models: Les Produits ::: product.product()

Comment: @MartianX try to change the domain to : `['|', ('default_code', '=', ''), ('default_code', '=', False)` to handle null value also not just empty string

Comment: and don't use `x` as variable names, sorry about the syntax error in the domain of `search_count`. let me know when you try this